# Renormalization theory in system with two coupling constants

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, renormalization, dimensional-analysis, critical-phenomena

Suppose a system has 2 coupling constants, $t$ (temperature) and $h$ (applied field). Let $K_{1}$ and $K_{2}$ be coupling constants, such that

$$\left[ \begin{array}{c} K_1 \\ K_2 \end{array} \right] = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \times \left[ \begin{array}{c} t \\ h \end{array} \right]$$

Under a rescaling $l$,

$$K'_1 = l^{y_1}K_1$$
$$K'_2 = l^{y_2}K_2$$

where $y_1,y_2 > 0$. Under this rescaling, the correlating length is reduced by a factor $l$:

$$\xi(K'_1,K'_2) = \frac{1}{l}\xi(K_1,K_2)$$

I'm supposed to show that

$$\xi(K_1,K_2) = K_2^{-1/y_2}\Phi(K_1K_2^{-y_1/y_2})$$

and study the asymptotic behaviour of $\Phi(x)$ for $x \sim 0 $ and $x \sim \infty$.

**My attempt**

The first part is easy to demonstrate, if we let $l = K_2^{-1/y_2}$.

For the second part:

- for $x \sim 0$, then $K_1 = 0$ and $K_2 \neq 0$, since $K_2$ must be finite (I don't know why), which yields $\Phi(0)$: $\Phi(x)$ is constant;
- for $x \sim \infty$, $K_2 = 0$ and $K_1 \neq 0$, but I don't know how $\Phi(x)$ should behave.

**Questions**

Why must $K_1$ or $K_2$ not be infinite and what is the asymptotic behaviour for the second case?

Comment: Hint: $K_1$ and $K_2$ are coupling constants close to the critical fixed point *divided by $k_BT$*. We know that the system represented by the critical fixed point is a system at its own critical point. May it have zero temperature? And what would be the consequence on the Hamiltonian if $K_2=\infty$?

Comment: @GiorgioP Ah! $T_c = 0$ would not, in fact, be a valid critical temperature. What about the other question?